# Unix time not calculated correctly

Tags: c

I have some weird bug and i am obviously cant figure out why it happens. I calculate the unixtime from argv[1] argument e.g. `20200303152000`. Most of the time the correct value of `1583248800` gets calculated and sometimes`1583245200`, which is wrong. This is my c code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  char t[14];
  strncpy(t, argv[1], 14);
  int timestamp[6];
  timestamp[0] = (((int)t[0] - 48) * 1000) + (((int)t[1] - 48) * 100) + (((int)t[2] - 48) * 10) + ((int)t[3] - 48);
  timestamp[1] = (((int)t[4] - 48) * 10) + ((int)t[5] - 48);
  timestamp[2] = (((int)t[6] - 48) * 10) + ((int)t[7] - 48);
  timestamp[3] = (((int)t[8] - 48) * 10) + ((int)t[9] - 48);
  timestamp[4] = (((int)t[10] - 48) * 10) + ((int)t[11] - 48);
  timestamp[5] = (((int)t[12] - 48) * 10) + ((int)t[13] - 48);

  struct tm timestampS;
  timestampS.tm_year = timestamp[0] - 1900;
  timestampS.tm_mon = timestamp[1] - 1;
  timestampS.tm_mday = timestamp[2];
  timestampS.tm_hour = timestamp[3] + 1;
  timestampS.tm_min = timestamp[4];
  timestampS.tm_sec = timestamp[5];

  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", timestamp[i]);
  }

  printf("%d\n", mktime(&timestampS));
  printf("%s\n", t);
  return 0;
}
```

The for loop is for debugging purpose only and actually prints the same values every time.
Does anyone of you have a clue what i am missing here?

Comment: This program should be fairly easy to debug. With a debugger.

Comment: Why are you telling snprintf that it can safely write 16 bytes into a 14 byte char array? And why are you using snprintf in the first place, rather than simply using argv[1], or perhaps copying (using strcpy) to a new, correctly-sized, char array?

Comment: Are you saying that, for one input, sometimes the program prints a correct value and sometimes it prints an incorrect value? Or are you saying that there are some inputs for which the program always prints the correct value and some inputs for which the program always prints incorrect values? In either case, give an input for which the program prints an incorrect value.

Comment: `char t[14]` isn't big enough to hold that input string, you didn't leave room for the null terminator. So you're getting undefined behavior and that causes inconsistent results.

Comment: I changed the code with strncpy but the same irrational behavior persists. The same input produces different output sometimes.

Comment: Both `strncpy` and `snprintf` are wrong. The key problem there is `char t[14]` defines an array of only 14 characters, which is insufficient to hold “20200303152000” because that is 14 characters, and both `strncpy` and `snprintf` write a null terminator, so you need at least 15 characters in the array. Except you do not need another array at all; the calculations for `timestamp` can be done directly from `argv[1][i]` instead of from `t[i]`. Additionally, all the `(int)` casts are unnecessary, and `48` should be changed to `'0'` for portability and readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timestampS` is not initialized, and you're not setting the `tm_isdst` field of `timestampS`.  This field indicates whether or not Daylight Saving Time is active or not.  This means `mktime` is reading an **indeterminate value** for this field.

Your results differ by 3600 seconds, so this would account for the issue.

If you don't know whether DST is active, set this field to -1.

Comment: Sample: `struct tm timestampS;` --> `struct tm timestampS = {.tm_isdst = -1 };` to zero all members aside from `.tm_isdst`.